# How to get different combinations in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given `Lista` each containing an id name (e.g. `a`), the
symbol `'='` and a comma separated list of values. I need to generate another list which is a combination of `'id= value'` substrings, such that each id-value combination exists in the input and each value is used exactly once.

```
Lista:
    [
    'a= aVal1,aVal2',
    'b=bVal1,bVal2,bVal3',
    'c= cVal1,cVal2',
    ]
```

Expected output:

```
Listb:
    [
    'a=aVal1& b=bVal1&c=cVal1',
    'a=aVal1&b=tyVal1&c=cVal2',
    'a=aVal1&b=tyVal2&c=tzVal1',
    'a=aVal1&b=tyVal2&c=tzVal2',
    ]
```

I tried to solve this question using [`itertools.permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.permutations) function, but I was unable to proceed further. What type of approach should I take to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show us the expected o/p

Comment: @Backtrack expected o/p is listb

Comment: why you did not used `a=aVal2`?

Comment: Take a look at itertools [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: @Kasra - I need a combinations , this is just a sample list.

Comment: @PM2Ring - It would be great if you could show  your way of approach in answer.

Comment: @Kasra I want to use `bval3` as well not just the common values. It is a combination problem.

Comment: @PM2Ring I think I have to use regex right?

Comment: You could use regex to split the strings in Lista, but it's easier just to use standard string functions. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Hi @ElizabethSusanJoseph  Check my update using string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't normally post complete working solutions to what look like homework problems, so consider yourself lucky. :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from itertools import product

lista = [
    'a=aVal1,aVal2',
    'b=bVal1,bVal2,bVal3',
    'c=cVal1,cVal2',
]

newlists = []
for s in lista:
    head, _, tail = s.partition('=')
    newlists.append(['%s=%s' % (head, u) for u in tail.split(',')])

listb = ['&'.join(t) for t in product(*newlists)]

for row in listb:
    print row
```

**output**

```
a=aVal1&b=bVal1&c=cVal1
a=aVal1&b=bVal1&c=cVal2
a=aVal1&b=bVal2&c=cVal1
a=aVal1&b=bVal2&c=cVal2
a=aVal1&b=bVal3&c=cVal1
a=aVal1&b=bVal3&c=cVal2
a=aVal2&b=bVal1&c=cVal1
a=aVal2&b=bVal1&c=cVal2
a=aVal2&b=bVal2&c=cVal1
a=aVal2&b=bVal2&c=cVal2
a=aVal2&b=bVal3&c=cVal1
a=aVal2&b=bVal3&c=cVal2
```

I've changed the name of your lists to lower case - Names beginning with an upper case letter like `Lista` and `Listb` are normally reserved for use as class names in Python.

If you don't understand any of the things I've done in this program, please ask and I'll try to explain.

---

You *could* do this in one line, but it's not very easy to read:

```
listb = ['&'.join(t)for t in product(*[['%s=%s'%(i,v)for v in j.split(',')]for i,j in[s.split('=')for s in lista]])]
```

:)

---

The string [`.partition()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) splits a string into 3 parts: the substring before the separator, the separator itself, and the substring after the separator.
So `head, _, tail = s.partition('=')` captures the id into `head` and all the associated values into `tail`.
I use `_` to capture the separator to indicate that we don't really need that value (since we already know that it's `=`).
The list comprehension on the next line splits the values up by using `.split(',')`.

Comment: what exactly is partition doing here?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l=[i.split('=') for i in a]
>>> g=[[i]+j.split(',') for i,j in l]
>>> ['&'.join(('='.join(m),'='.join(k),'='.join(t))) for m,k,t in (product(*[list(combinations(i,2)) for i in g],repeat=1))]
['a= aVal1&b=bVal1&c= cVal1', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal1&c=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal1& cVal1=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal2&c= cVal1', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal2&c=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal2& cVal1=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal3&c= cVal1', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal3&c=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&b=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&bVal1=bVal2&c= cVal1', 'a= aVal1&bVal1=bVal2&c=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&bVal1=bVal2& cVal1=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&bVal1=bVal3&c= cVal1', 'a= aVal1&bVal1=bVal3&c=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&bVal1=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&bVal2=bVal3&c= cVal1', 'a= aVal1&bVal2=bVal3&c=cVal2', 'a= aVal1&bVal2=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal1&c= cVal1', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal1&c=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal1& cVal1=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal2&c= cVal1', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal2&c=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal2& cVal1=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal3&c= cVal1', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal3&c=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&b=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&bVal1=bVal2&c= cVal1', 'a=aVal2&bVal1=bVal2&c=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&bVal1=bVal2& cVal1=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&bVal1=bVal3&c= cVal1', 'a=aVal2&bVal1=bVal3&c=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&bVal1=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&bVal2=bVal3&c= cVal1', 'a=aVal2&bVal2=bVal3&c=cVal2', 'a=aVal2&bVal2=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal1&c= cVal1', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal1&c=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal1& cVal1=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal2&c= cVal1', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal2&c=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal2& cVal1=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal3&c= cVal1', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal3&c=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&b=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal1=bVal2&c= cVal1', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal1=bVal2&c=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal1=bVal2& cVal1=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal1=bVal3&c= cVal1', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal1=bVal3&c=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal1=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal2=bVal3&c= cVal1', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal2=bVal3&c=cVal2', ' aVal1=aVal2&bVal2=bVal3& cVal1=cVal2']
```

---

explanation :

First you need to split your string list with `=` then create `g` as following :

```
>>> g
[['a', ' aVal1', 'aVal2'], ['b', 'bVal1', 'bVal2', 'bVal3'], ['c', ' cVal1', 'cVal2']]
```

now you need to create the combinations of the element of list `g` with len 2 and after that you need a `production` of that result!*Note* that we need to pickup one tuple from each list of below result :

```
>>> [list(combinations(i,2)) for i in g]
[[('a', ' aVal1'), ('a', 'aVal2'), (' aVal1', 'aVal2')], [('b', 'bVal1'), ('b', 'bVal2'), ('b', 'bVal3'), ('bVal1', 'bVal2'), ('bVal1', 'bVal3'), ('bVal2', 'bVal3')], [('c', ' cVal1'), ('c', 'cVal2'), (' cVal1', 'cVal2')]]
```

Comment: Wait I am checking all your solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have take a look on `itertools.product`, that may be what you are looking for.

You may easily convert `listA` to 3 lists:

```
a = ['aVal1', 'aVal2']
b = ['bVal1', 'bVal2', 'bVal3']
c = ['cVal1', 'cVal2']
```

then you may try

```
for x in itertools.product(a, b, c):
   print x
```

x will be what you want, all the remain work are string concatenating, or string formating.

**Update**

For more detail, you can use this

```
all_the_list = []
listB = []
for i in listA:
    name, values = i.split('=');
    k = values.strip().split(',');
    all_the_list.append(k)

// then product the out put
for aV, bV, cV in itertools.product(*all_the_list):
    listB.append('a=%s&b=%s&c=%s'%(aV, bV, cV))
```

Hope this help

Comment: `Lista:
    [
    'a= aVal1,aVal2',
    'b=bVal1,bVal2,bVal3',
    'c= cVal1,cVal2',
    ]` lista is a seperate list